# What are various Fields (with documentation) for Form Fields in PDF Form

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I looking for various Fields and their documentation for PDF Forms like we have for the Html like text Fields, SelectBox.

I could not find it. Just like we have these

```
"FieldType" = "Text"
"FieldType": "Button"
"FieldJustification": "Left"
```

I want to know what all options , attributes are there so that I know them better.

Something like [this](http://documentation.scribus.net/index.php/PDF_Forms) but from the official source.

Answer (score 1):

For information on the PDF format it generally is a good idea to have a look at the specification, i.e. currently ISO 32000-1:2008 which Adobe makes publicly available [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Chapter 12.7 "Interactive Forms" explains the AcroForm PDF forms, section 12.7.4 "Field Types" explains the available field types.

If you do also want to consider dynamic forms according to the Adobe XML Architecture, you also should lookup the XML Forms Architecture (XFA) Specification, made available by Adobe in version 3.3 [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/xfa_spec_3_3.pdf).